# Android Achievements - Achievable More Than Once

Tags: android, achievements

I am new to Achievements in Android and trying to find if there is something similar to the property 'Achievable More Than Once' in iOS. There is no similar property when creating an Achievement in Android.

An achievement can be earned multiple times(like answering correctly 5 times in a row) but I did not find anything related to this. I tried unlocking the same achievement multiple times which did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find anything like that in the Google Play Game Services.

Closest to what you want might be an **Incremental Achievement**, as shown in the [Achievements document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements). However, a maximum value is needed for this.

Following your example, what you could do is implement an achievement "*Five successive correct answers 100 times*", with an increasing counter for the achievement. When it reaches 100, the achievement is completed and will not be updated anymore.